# Tkinter GUI Image w/ Button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am currently working on an interactive GUI using Tkinter that works w/ a BMP image. Essentially, I want to be able to click a button that then allows the user to designate any three points on the image, which would then produce a best fit ellipse and return the smallest value within the ellipse.

I am able to produce the BMP image, however I do not know how to produce a button w/ the image. How would I go about doing that?

After the button is clicked, it would execute a function that would change the mouse cursor to a crosshair, then take in any three points on the image w/ clicks and save them to variable which I would work w/ later to produce the elipse. I would want the clicks to produce maybe a red dot to signify its position.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def bmpGUI():
    top=Tk()

    top.title("BMP Image")

    image = Image.open("ap41.ddr.brf.sdat.bmp")
    widthBMP, heightBMP = image.size
    tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    w = Canvas(top, width=widthBMP+200, height=heightBMP)
    w.create_image((widthBMP/2,heightBMP/2),image=tkimage)

    w.pack()

    top.mainloop()
    return

def main():
    bmpGUI()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I added 200px to the width, to show that I wanted sort of an interactive sidebar alongside the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a more helpful variable name for the canvas than `w`, also in order for this to work, the canvas will need to be made global

```
tkimage.configure(cursor="plus")
w.bind("<Button-1>", imgClick)

pos = []
def imgClick(e):
    x=w.canvasx(e.x)
    y=w.canvasy(e.y)
    pos.append((x,y))
    w.create_line(x-5,y,x+5,y, fill="red", tags="crosshair")
    w.create_line(x,y-5,x,y+5, fill="red", tags="crosshair")
```

When you have all the 3 positions, you can just use `w.delete("crosshair")`.